# Java High Level Game Library Recommendation - Maintained Alternatives to Slick2D?

Tags: library, java, api, programming, game-development

I am developing games in Java. I prefer extendable and high-level game frameworks–but nonetheless, I have tried many low-level bindings too. So these are the ones I have used/researched about. Some pros and cons listed below are just educated guesses, so please point it out if anything is wrong.

Java2D

Pros

- High-level
- Easy to use
- Good Documentation

Cons

- Lacks powerful low-level bindings such as OpenGL bindings.
- Pretty slow compared to other OpenGL-based options.

JOGL

Pros

- Powerful
- Very easy to adapt OpenGL code
- Easy to create a wrapper for

Cons

- Weird documentation/support
- Small user base

Slick2D

Pros

- Very easy to use
- LWJGL wrapper, very powerful
- Similar to Java2D
- Perfect for my needs
- Big user base
- Good support

Cons

- Dead since 2 years ago
- Uses an old version of LWJGL, and therefore an old version of OpenGL
- Not recommended by many people, for the cons above

LibGDX

Pros

- Recommended by many people
- Big user base
- OK Support/Documentation

Cons

- y-up
- y-up
- y-up
- Weird
- Feels really uncomfortable
- 1 line, glOrtho(...), in normal OpenGL turns into 3 lines OrthographicCamera... blah blah blah
- Many projects for 1 game is a bit weird
- Requires me to use the project setup manager

---

So, to put it shortly, can you recommend me a Java game framework/API/whatever that...

- Supports both low-level bindings and high-level wrappers of them
- Supports direct OpenGL calls
- (Optionally) Has an inbuilt game loop and collision detection
- Supports basic features regarding sprites
- Has good documentation/user base
- Is alive and well-maintained